# What data format is used to send query results from Microsoft SQL Server to ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have tried searching the msdn and google but unable to find any sources that specifically touches on this question. At the moment I can only assume A JSON is used.

If so then I guess the SQL server would process the query received, and send the results in a JSON format back to the web app. Which also leads me to ask, is the query also sent to the SQL Server in a JSON format?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sql Server does not communicate using JSON. Why do you care what "format" it is in, you do not get to do anything with the "format" anyways as everything is abstracted. In .NET you will always use either ado.net or an ORM (or other library) that is built on ado.net to communicate with Sql Server. The only thing you can specify is the communication protocol, do that in the sql server network configuration tool and then specify the corresponding options in any connection string.

Comment: @Igor I need to know this as its a requirement for a school project. Additionally, I have never asked this question before and curious to find out how it works.

Comment: @Luv2Learn Why is this a requirement for a school project? SQL Server communicates using its own protocol, and you likely have no valid reason to know the exact details of that protocol.

Comment: I think you probably did not understand the assignment correctly. Maybe your instructor wanted to know what the format is of data that is transferred between a web application you built and the client. Again, in .net sql server communication is done using ado.net. It makes 0 difference if the code that is using ado.net is a web app, a console app, or anything else. The underlying format of the data that is communicated between the ado.net library and Sql Server should also not matter at all to you or the other 99.99% of us that work in .net.

Comment: Thanks the Wikipedia page is very helpful. Even if my question is not what the assignment was really asking for I was curious to find out, be it relevant or not.

Answer (score -1):

The [Microsoft SQL Server Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) provides the information I will need to know for Microsoft SQL Server If I choose to dive deep into the mechanics of the components/services.

For the original question of this post, communication is done through TDS protocol as stated in the section below.

> The protocol layer implements the external interface to SQL Server. All operations that can be invoked on SQL Server are communicated to it via a Microsoft-defined format, called Tabular Data Stream (TDS). TDS is an application layer protocol, used to transfer data between a database server and a client. Initially designed and developed by Sybase Inc. for their Sybase SQL Server relational database engine in 1984, and later by Microsoft in Microsoft SQL Server, TDS packets can be encased in other physical transport dependent protocols, including TCP/IP, named pipes, and shared memory. Consequently, access to SQL Server is available over these protocols. In addition, the SQL Server API is also exposed over web services.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#Architecture

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. You should include the important details directly in your answer.

Comment: Not only that. The link doesn't even go to a page with the answer.

Comment: Made changes to answer according to what you guys pointed out.